# How to make hibernate.cfg.xml to a datasource bean

Tags: hibernate

I have a hibernate.cfg.xml file, but I'd like to reference it as a dataSource bean. Is there any way to do this? All I have is :

```
<beans:bean id="foo" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

but its not a dataSource. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To add a bit of context, I'd like to integrate Spring Security in my app and one of the ways to provide a database as a source for the authentication manager is as follows (taken from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#what-is-acegi-security)):

```
   <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="securityDataSource"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Where “securityDataSource” is the name of a DataSource bean in the application context, pointing at a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. If you're not using the `hibernate.cfg.xml` anywhere else, you can eliminate it altogether and just use Spring's configuration (see below)
2. If you need `hibernate.cfg.xml` for some reason (you're using it elsewhere), then keep that file and add Spring configuration

---

Example configuration (notice database access is in a separate `dataSource` bean)

```
<beans:bean id="foo" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                ...
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>some.package</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource" />

<bean id="c3p0DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    scope="singleton"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${jdbc.user}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.pw}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

You can see more information about the configuration options in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using hibernate than why to use jdbc you can use spring bean for this like this

```
<security:authentication-manager>
<security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.something.MyAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

where MyAuthenticationProvider is Spring bean that implements AuthenticationProvider.
you can also checkout following link for more help [Link1](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) and [Link2](http://beansgocrazy.blogspot.in/2011/07/custom-authentication-with-spring.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create directly from spring no need of cfg.xml file.

dialect
                50
                false
                false
                false
            
        
   
You can configure all Hibernate properties here...